# Android Face Detection and applying the color on some parts of the face like cheeck,lips etc

Tags: android, face-detection

Can anyone tell me how to apply color for some part of the body like lips,cheeks,nose.

1. I successfully ran the Google mobile vision Api for detecting face and landmarks of face like nose, mouth, cheeks etc.
2. My goal is to apply color to lips of the face like makeup lipstick.
3. I find the mouth of face with RIGHT_MOUTH, LEFT_MOUTH, BOTTOM_MOUTH coordinates. So I spotted the mouth exactly on the face with 3 dots (left, right, bottom).
4. I need to apply some color (Any) to the mouth exactly, so that if the person opens his mouth then its going to apply only on the lips.
5. I tried to draw an oval based on the points, but no luck. It's showing the oval around the mouth which is not the correct way, I thought.

I need to apply the color to the lips exactly.So how to calculate the  lips/mouth regions exactly.

Note: Other than openCV library

I there any way to calculate the regions of the lips ? Or any other.

Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which platform are you using?

Comment: I am trying to develop in Android Platform.

Comment: had any luck in solving this problem?

Comment: @HariPrasad have you find any solution or SDK to achieve this kind of feature?

Comment: Dude!!! Answer . What did you do?